# High-level algorithm/engineering questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Can I ask high-level algorithm/engineering type questions on Stack Overflow?

If not, is there any Stack Exchange site where this type of question is acceptable?

For example: I have a signal I am trying analyze. I want to ask how to go about detecting the start of the signal when there is noise present.

I have read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but I'm still unsure.

Comment: Just click on the Stack Exchange icon in the top right corner to see the complete list of available sub-sites. If you've found a promising one, then check the help center for "What topics can I ask about here?".

Comment: You might want to go over previous asked [site-recommendations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) and have a look at [the site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid#technology) and bring down the potential of 160 sites down to a handful. When you have a specific prepared question and are still unsure where to ask, either post on MSE or the site specific meta (but you need 5 rep for that). My comment extends what is already mentioned in the tag wiki: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/site-recommendation/info

Comment: It's a little hard to firmly say what site is appropriate based on the limited information presented, but if you have a language-independent question about signal processing, [Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com) might be a good place to go. If your question involves specific code in a particular language or framework, there might still be a place for it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thanks @BradLarson. I want to ask about appropriate techniques first and then once I have that, then I understand that because I'm programming in Python, I can bring it back here

Comment: If you have a specific question about a specific algorithm, it would be on topic here (questions about algorithms are *explicitly* on-topic here). Is your concern that your potential question could be considered too broad here, or are you not sure what algorithm you're using yet? If it's more of a conceptual question, Signal Processing SE or (maybe) Software Engineering SE could be better fits.

Comment: Some questions aren't for any SE site if you can properly search for answers online already. Open ended questions are seldom ontopic. You might however have a look on the Software engineering site and see if it's ontopic there. There are also 2 computer science SE sites, one for theoretical stuff only and one with more applied algorithms.

Comment: "Explicitly on-topic" or not, you may find a lot of people wanting to close your question for being too broad. Not to say don't ask it, but rather to suggest you spend some time to craft it to be very specific.

Comment: @Tom There are 66 SE sites in the technology category alone, and I've consistently found ambiguities regarding which questions are appropriate where. "Just find one yourself" is hardly a helpful suggestion.

Comment: @KyleStrand "Do my research" isn't useful as well.

Comment: @Tom Literally any (answerable) question on any SE site could be answered without asking SE if sufficient research effort were put into it.

Comment: Help page for [electrical engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) and help page for [signal processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help), both have advice on what types of questions to ask.  Either one of these SE sites have folks who can answer signal processing questions.

Answer (score 5):

The main scope of the site is "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development". You first have to fulfill that criteria, because this site focus on the practical aspects of the software development, creation of software. Is like the difference between the theory and the practice.

Full blown CS questions don't lend themselves to fit the scope of SO, since we expect the possible answers to be finite and the questions to be reasonably scoped, which tend to fail in theoretical questions.

If you "have a signal I am trying analyze" and need help in the practical aspects, you could ask the question here. But if you "have a signal I am trying analyze", but you don't know exactly what the approaches are to analyze signals, the site may not be very helpful.