# An [np]-hard question

Tags: discussion, tags

So I normally peruse [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) questions, and recently got tag-editing capability.  I noticed that sometimes folks like to tag the common abbreviation of [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) to [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np).  OK, simple, ask meta to synonymize it, right?

Maaaybe not.  As per [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np)'s tag wiki:

> NP ("nondeterministic polynomial") is a complexity class of decision problems that can be solved by a nondeterministic Turing machine in polynomial time. Equivalently, it is the set of decision problems for which an answer can be verified in polynomial time by a deterministic Turing machine.

[Wait, is that even on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345467/high-level-algorithm-engineering-questions) There seems to be quite a few questions and answers in [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) along those lines, and I don't know enough theoretical CS to judge, so I'm bringing it to meta!

Basically I see 3 options:

1. NP-complexity is off-topic for SO, and therefore burninate [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) questions on it and then synonimize [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) with [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy)
2. NP-complexity is on-topic for SO, but rare/esoteric enough to justify renaming [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) to [np-complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np-complexity) and then synonimizing [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) with [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) or burninating [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) entirely.
3. Do nothing, retagging the occasional question is not high-effort and [np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) is just as or more valid as a computer science term than as an alias for a `python` package.

But I'm not even sure which to request, if any.  Or if that last option is just my impostor syndrome acting up.

Comment: NP complexity seems on-topic to me. A programmer can have expertise in approaching problems relating to NP-complexity. numpy users should type the three extra letters for their tag.

Comment: @khelwood While I don't disagree, there may be *some* benefit in renaming [np] to [np-complexity], if it is causing confusion and/or mistagging.

Comment: `np` should not be a synonym of `numpy` even when NP questions were off-topic. NP is a common abbreviation of "nondeterministic polynomial" and widely used in computer science, whereas NP as a abbreviation of NumPy is only/mainly used in the Python community. So this (for most) unexpected link to NumPy could result in incorrect tagging. I would then rather suggest to rename the tag, like suggest in the question, and block the re-creation of an `np` tag to prevent further ambiguity.

Comment: The bulk of mistagging comes from `np` frequently being imported as `import numpy as np`. I support renaming np to np-complexity, but in the style of a burnination and rather getting rid of np entirely rather than renaming it precisely to prevent ambiguous use. `np` potentially has several uses that leads to a high risk of misuse. TL;DR: move polynomial questions to np-complexity, move numpy questions to the numpy tag, and burn the tag to prevent further ambiguous use

Comment: So option 2B: rename the np tag np-complexity and don't have a plain np tag at all.

Comment: Another possible collision is for [Notepad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad_%28software%29) or [Notepad++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B) (though I have *never* seen it - only [N++, NP++, npp, and NPP](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html)).

Answer (score 3):

Considering that the [np-hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np-hard) tag also exists, it does not make sense to have both. It is less often used however:

- 164 [np-hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np-hard) questions
- 390 [questions tagged `np` but not `python`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np+-python) (note that some might just be missing the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag and thus still be about NumPy)
- 73 [questions tagged `np` and `python`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np+python) – most of which seem to be about NumPy

I think it would probably make more sense to use [np-hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np-hard) to avoid confusion, so a [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) should be executed. I don't think a synonym request is appropriate, considering the current misuse.

[np](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/np) should then not be used anymore.

Comment: I don't think NP-hard is the same as NP.

Comment: @khelwood Indeed, but I don't think it makes sense to have both tags either. P and NP-complete are both part of NP, NP-complete is also part of NP-hard. All of them are part of [tag:complexity-theory] (4228 questions). Not sure we need tags for each, and I think questions about one will most likely also be about the others.