# Are programming tool name origin questions considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is the correct way to handle a question about the naming origins of a library, programming language or a software tool?

For example:

> Why is Python named the way it is?

According to *[Are questions about software tools on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330413/are-questions-about-software-tools-on-topic)*, questions about software tools are on-topic in certain cases, though I don't know whether this falls within such case. If not, which close reason should I use?

Comment: Think it's ok. [Similar question example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499857/seaborn-why-import-as-sns)

Comment: Is there going to be any sort of useful answer to that kind of question?  What good will it do for you to know the answer?

Comment: @fbueckert I'm just asking this because I encountered such question and I voted to close it, but I'm now seeing some comments on that question and on on other media that made me re-evaluate my votes, hence why I asked this meta question.

Comment: How would that be a _practical programming question_?

Comment: _Potentially_ on topic over on SE.SE: https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5633/is-programming-history-on-topic

Comment: @yivi You're right, reading the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) made me question my actions, because it mentions that questions about software tools can be on-topic. However, I must have read over the sentence below it, because it clearly mentions that it should be a "practical" question that's unique to software development, and in this case it isn't.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Of course, that thread also says "no trivia" which I would argue name origins fall under.

Comment: That's reasonable, @JohnMontgomery; I emphasized the "potentially" on purpose. :)

Comment: We just need the [Magic-8 Ball](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1696/320339) feature.

Comment: If the origin of the name of a tool, language etc. can be found by simply looking the relevant entry up on Wikipedia is there anywhere where it would be on-topic?

Comment: @spodger that's lack of research, not topicness. Topicness is what the topic of the question is, not how much effort the asker put into asking the question.

Comment: Wouldn't the question be more suited to another forum, rather than SO?  Perhaps SuperUser?

Comment: @fbueckert Strictly speaking, "not useful" is a downvote reason. "Not constructive" is a close reason.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It's not on topic. It's not a practical question specific to software development. Heck, it's not even a software development question. Close it with a custom reason.

Comment: "Too broad" or "Primarily opinion based" may be useful here as well, since asking us why this was named the way it was would require a Wikipedia post, or could be entirely subjective (like Acegi was back in the day, but again I only learned that from both Wikipedia and lots of Spring conferences).

Comment: @Makoto if someone needs to bend to make those reasons fit, better going explicit with the reason on a text box. Clarity over everything.

Comment: Shouldn't this be closed then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41499857/seaborn-why-import-as-sns (from this question's comments). Amazingly, the selected answer is a Wikipedia copy-paste

Comment: I know the example question is just that - an example, but....Its probably a bad example as the answer is [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/general.html#why-is-it-called-python)...

Comment: @That1Guy still, why something is called the way it's called is not part of the software development process. It's trivia.

Comment: @Braiam Understood - I'm not arguing its relevance - just that its not a perfect example of "Primarily Opinion Based" as was mentioned by Makoto. I should have been more clear about that in my initial comment.

Comment: @That1Guy then you should address Makoto comment, by pinging it.

Comment: @Braiam You should check out the "I should have been more clear about that" portion of the comment you're replying to, bud ;)

Comment: @That1Guy still, Makoto has not been pinged.

Answer (score 15):

From [Don't Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

This is not a "practical, answerable question based on an actual problem that you face." It's also definitely a "chatty, open-ended question." So, it's off-topic.

Comment: I agree its not practical and *potentially* chatty. I have to disagree about it being open-ended. The answer is [officially documented](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/general.html#why-is-it-called-python)

Comment: @That1Guy That's true - although, given that the OP could Google that in 5 seconds, isn't that all the more reason to downvote and close the question for lack of research effort?

Comment: I did a poor job being clear in all of my comments today...I'm not advocating for keeping the question open - I was simply pointing out that the example with Python does have a canonical answer so close reasons such as "Primarily Opinion Based" and the like don't quite fit in my opinion. I'm also not sure (and maybe this is new) that lack of research effort is a valid reason to close questions on SO. There are plenty of questions that can be Googled in 5 seconds - and most of them lead back to SO ;). Again just to be clear - I don't think the question is appropriate for SO.