# Are questions about using codementor.io on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I found some posts here that mentioned codementor.io. Few days ago I start using it as mentor. So far, I briefly explored their help center and online community. Also I already sent some question to their support email address but I'm so used to the SO style and I'm wondering if using the codementor.io code editor will be on topic here.

I think that those questions could be on-topic because the scope of this site include **tools commonly used by programmers,** and as I already mentioned, I learned about codementor.io due to mentions done here on Meta SO and while I was writing this also found mentions about codementor.io on the main site, but there isn't an specific tag.

In the past I saw that sometimes questions about similar tools are migrated to Web Applications.

Side note: I think that it will be usual that my mentoring session require the use of external tools, mostly Google Apps Script, G Suite Document Editors, desktop code editors, but I think that the most relevant code snippets should be added to the codementor.io code editor as a summary of the mentoring session.

Related

- [Are questions about software tools on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/330413/1595451)

Comment: I'm not sure if it will. The point of SO is to collate the answers on-site, not on-site pointing to an off-site resource (if I'm understanding how the site you linked works).

Comment: That said, SO is clearly not for new developers, learning programming from the ground up. Until SO has an offering like codementor, it doesn't seem like there would be a conflict to ask about it here.
Also, thanks for bringing my attention to codementor. Seems like a very complementary tool to SO and I'm excited to try it.

Comment: @Script47 There are [1.6k questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsfiddle?tab=Votes) about jsfiddle (Some are probably tagged wrongly). OP is asking about the code editor in codementor.io. I mean, it's not as popular as jsfiddle but...

Comment: @adiga in that case, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: I guess they can be. Whether the majority of questions are actually going to be on-topic... hard to know..

Comment: I wanted to say "questions about using codementor.io editor" but as there is already an answer I'm no sure if I just make the edit directly or add a new paragraph to avoid to give the idea that I'm proposing to post code there instead of SO questions (like some people does with jsfiddler and other tools)

Answer (score 3):

#### It depends.

The "tools commonly used by programmers" exception is really intended for rich, complex environments like IDEs. Computers and books are also tools commonly used by programmers but they are not OK to ask about here, for example.

Codementor.io is a site where people get one-on-one assistance with problems they have with their code, similar to the point of Stack Overflow (except here on SO it's not one-on-one attention or a private session). Right off the bat you are in a weird spot where you're asking us to help with using a competitor site (albeit not a direct one). That in and of itself is not necessarily a deal-breaker, of course, just seems weird (like asking how to use expertsexchange, another SO competitor).

- Questions about using Codementor, e.g. *the site* or *the service* will probably be off-topic because that's general computing use (using a website) or interpersonal advice (or some other weird area), respectively.
- Questions about using the Codementor code editor *might* be on-topic (I'm not familiar with it), if it is sufficiently low-level and complex enough that you interact with it by writing code, setting flags and other variables, etc (think Visual Studio, Notepad++, Codepen.io).

  However, if it's rather a WYSIWYG editor with some code/syntax support (like Stack Overflow's editor), then it'd be off-topic (just like it'd be off-topic to ask about using some other random site's WYSIWYG editor).

I imagine such questions would get more attention and better answers over on Codementor's own community area at https://www.codementor.io/community, though. But maybe that's not what the community area is for.

Comment: As I mentioned on a comment to the question, I wanted to say "questions about using codementor.io code editor". I didn't think about what exactly I could ask, but my first thought is to ask about using jsdoc on code snippets on, another possible question about how to structure code  for better navigability / readability

Comment: @Rubén as far as how to structure code, that would be off-topic under the "primarily opinion-based" reason.

Comment: AFAIK  https://www.codementor.io/community doesn't has anything similar to SO (including the lack of something similar to Meta) So far it looks to me to be a "primarily-opinion based" place for IT people.